# Dr racket define error in student language. define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 3 extra parts

Tags: scheme, racket, sqrt, racket-student-languages

When I write code in Dr Racket, I got error message

> unsaved-editor:8:2: define: expected only one expression for the
>   function body, but found 3 extra parts in: (define (improve guess x)
>   (average guess (/ x guess)))

But this code can run in *Racket* or *repl.it*.

I want to know why error is happening in Dr Racket and is my code really wrong?

My code is this:

```lisp
(define (average x y) (/ (+ x y) 2))

(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (sqrt1 x)
  (define (good-enough? guess x)
    (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001))
  (define (improve guess x)
    (average guess (/ x guess)))
  (define (sqrt-iter guess x)
    (if (good-enough? guess x)
        guess
        (sqrt-iter (improve guess x) x)))
  (sqrt-iter 1.0 x))

(sqrt1 9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is OK for Scheme/Racket. However *Student Language* is a subset of Scheme, highly limited so it's easier for beginners. It's also used in *How To Design Programs* book. You can read more about Student Languages (actually there is five of them) on https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/index.html.

In case of `define` there are important limitations:

1. You can have only one expression in the function body.
2. In function body you can only use expressions, not definitions (so no `define` inside `define`).

To make your code valid for *Student Language*, depending on *Level* (Beginner, Intermediate etc), you can:

- use `letrec*` or `local` instead of `define` for all local definitions

or

- define `good-enough`, `improve` and `sqrt-iter` as top level functions.

Comment: To make code valid for student languages you can also move internal definitions into [`local`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/intermediate.html?q=local#%28form._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-intermediate..rkt%29._local%29%29). Moving existing `define` forms into `local` will be easier than rewriting them into a letrec, especially for function definitions

Comment: @AlexKnauth Depends on the student language required. The two starting with "Beginner" doesn't have `local`

Comment: The two starting with "Beginner" don't have letrec or let, either. Any *SL that has letrec, also has local, from Intermediate Student Language up

Comment: @AlexKnauth and Sylwester - Thanks for the comments, I modified my answer acordingly.